# axis2 web service client with client certificate

Tags: java, apache-axis, webservice-client, client-certificates

I have written a java program which uses axis2 libraries to call a webservice via a stub. This has to be done in a secure way using a client certificate. That's the reason why I was looking for a way to reference my keystore and truststore containing the needed certificates.
I have searched the internet and found the following lines of code to accomplish the latter request:

```
File keystoreFile = new File("C:\\storage\\mykeystore");
URL keystoreURL = keystoreFile.toURI().toURL();
File truststoreFile = new File("C:\\storage\\cacerts");
URL truststoreURL = truststoreFile.toURI().toURL();
Protocol authhttps = new Protocol("https",     newAuthSSLProtocolSocketFactory(keystoreURL, kspwd, truststoreURL, "changeit"), 443);
Protocol.registerProtocol("https", authhttps);


String endpoint = "https://*url_to_endpoint*";
TestServiceStub stub = new TestServiceStub(endpoint);
...
```

When executing my program I receive a handshake error.
I am not sure if the above lines are sufficient for presenting the client certificate to the invoked web service endpoint. As I am pretty sure that I have set up the keystore and truststore correctly I assume that they perhaps don't get really loaded or applied, but I am not sure.

On the internet I have found a couple of similar requests but didn't find any information leading me to a solution.

So any hint concerning this issue is very welcome.

Comment: You want to use two-way authentication, don't you?

Comment: Yes, two-way authentication.